# Converting CSV file to xts

Tags: r, xts

I have a CSV file containing data with the first column in Unix time stamp. How can I convert it to xts form directly? Currently I am trying to read the file and convert using `as.xts`, but I get error messages every way I try.

An example of a code I used:

```
Data <- read.zoo("data.csv", index.column = 1, origin="01/01/1970",
                 sep = ",", header = TRUE, FUN = as.POSIXct)
as.xts(Data)
```

1st 2 lines of the csv:

```
1366930371  143.7   0.25275
1366930368  143.7   0.02664867
```

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297231/r-converting-a-data-frame-to-xts

Comment: Please provide an example of the code you used to try and read the file. Also, the first few lines of the file would be helpful.

Comment: See `?read.zoo` and also the `zoo-read` vignette.

Answer (score 0):

There could be several things wrong.  First is that the first 2 lines of your "csv" are tab-separated, not comma-separated.  Next, you specify `header=TRUE`, but the first 2 lines do not have a header.  Third, `origin=` is in the wrong format.  It should be `yyyy-mm-dd`.

This works:

```
library(xts)
Lines <- "1366978862,133.08,0.48180896
1366978862,133.08,0.5"
tc <- textConnection(Lines)
Data <- read.zoo(tc, sep=",", FUN=function(i) as.POSIXct(i, origin="1970-01-01"))
close(tc)
Data <- as.xts(Data)
```

Comment: Thank you, the file comma separated and it does have headers, but the origin was wrong! works now