# error in row name conversion in R for a data frame

Tags: r, xts

I'm using `R 3.0.2` and I loaded a csv into a dataframe that I want to convert to `xts` format.

my data looks something like this

```
head(data)
          V1     V2      V3      V4      V5      V6      V7      V8      V9
1 1999-01-04 1.1812 1.18120 1.18120 1.18120 1.18120 1.18120 1.18120 1.18120
2 1999-01-05 1.1760 1.17860 1.17860 1.17860 1.17860 1.17860 1.17860 1.17860
3 1999-01-06 1.1636 1.17360 1.17360 1.17360 1.17360 1.17360 1.17360 1.17360
4 1999-01-07 1.1672 1.17200 1.17200 1.17200 1.17200 1.17200 1.17200 1.17200
5 1999-01-08 1.1554 1.16868 1.16868 1.16868 1.16868 1.16868 1.16868 1.16555
6 1999-01-11 1.1534 1.16613 1.16613 1.16613 1.16613 1.16613 1.16312 1.15990
```

following advice from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297231/r-converting-a-data-frame-to-xts) I tried to convert the row name as follows

```
rownames(data) = data[1]
```

however I get the following error which I can't find my way around

```
Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : 
  invalid 'row.names' length
```

Comment: Try `rownames(data) = data[, 1]`.

Comment: And, Dirk's answer there is the best one to follow if your end goal is conversion to xts. `dataxts <- xts(data[,-1], order.by=data[,1])`. That basically translates to "use the data from all columns except the first, ordered by the time values found in the first column".

Comment: @AnandaMahto dirks answer gave me an error, 
  `order.by requires an appropriate time-based object`

Comment: Well you need to convert your first column first -- `as.Date()` say -- but beware of the pitfall of `stringsAsFactors` etc.  But there are dozens of 'how do I create an xts' posts around.

Comment: @pyCthon, please post your edit as an answer (and *accept* it) to indicate to others that the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based off the very generous comments
here is a simple solution

```
rownames(data) <- as.Date(data[,1]) 
dataxts <- xts(data[,-1], order.by=data[,1])
```

Comment: I think you want `data[,1] <- as.Date(data[,1])`, possibly with an `as.character(data[,1])` depending on how you read the data.  Making rownames a Date object does not make the first column one, and that is what you use here.

Comment: Perhaps for your benefit, you can explore a little and try to understand *why* the solution I shared in the comments work. See for instance `str(data[1])` as opposed to `str(data[[1]])` or `str(data[, 1])`. Also note from `?xts` that "`order.by`" is *a corresponding vector of unique times/dates*.