# Moving from zoo to xts object

Tags: r, time-series, xts

I have various financial data that I am trying to merge into an `xts` object so I can perform multiple statistical analyses.  I am having difficulty, however, with dates when moving from the original data to a `zoo` object to an `xts` object.

For instance, I read in some hedge fund return data, change the report date variable using the `ymd` function from the `lubridate` package, create a `zoo` object, then just as a check create a timeSeries object. All seems to be OK, but I continue to get an error when I attempt to create the `xts` object, as shown below:

```
hfIndexes$ReportDt <- ymd(hfIndexes$ReportDt)
hfIndexesZoo <- zoo(hfIndexes,order.by="ReportDt")
hfIndexesTimeSeries <- as.timeSeries(hfIndexesZoo)
hfIndexesXTS <- as.xts(hfIndexesZoo)
Error in xts(coredata(x), order.by = order.by, frequency = frequency,  : 
  order.by requires an appropriate time-based object
```

What do I need to do to ensure that I have the correct time-based object to create the desired `xts` object?

Comment: `"ReportDt"` is a character string, not a time-based object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [R: Converting a data frame to xts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297231/r-converting-a-data-frame-to-xts)

Comment: even when adding the "order.by" argument, I get the same error:
lsHoldingsXTS <-as.xts(lsHoldingsZoo, order.by = "ReportDt")
Error in xts(coredata(x), order.by = order.by, frequency = frequency,  : 
  order.by requires an appropriate time-based object

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich - I agree that "ReportDt" appears to not be a time-based object, but I thought the "ymd" function from package "lubridate" converted YYYYMMDD character data into PosixCT data, which is what shows to be in the data environment console.  Also, I thought I needed a time-based object to formulate a timeSeries object, which I am doing (I think) when using the "as.timeSeries" function without error.  I'm having difficulty trying to understand what I am doing incorrectly.

Comment: You convert `hfIndexes$ReportDt` to `POSIXct`.  Then you tell the `zoo` constructor to use the character string `"ReportDt"` as the index.  Look at the `hfIndexesZoo` object you've created, and I'm sure it's not what you think it is.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich - Thanks for being so patient with me, and helping me see where I am going wrong, but I still don't see how "ReportDt" is a string. When I look at its class it's a POSIXct.  Even if I change the name to not confuse myself, I still get an error:
lsHoldings$ReportDate <- ymd(lsHoldings$ReportDt)
> lsHoldingsZoo <- zoo(lsHoldings,order.by = "ReportDate")
> lsHoldingsXTS <-as.xts(lsHoldingsZoo, order.by = "ReportDate")
Error in xts(coredata(x), order.by = order.by, frequency = frequency,  : 
  order.by requires an appropriate time-based object

What am I missing?

Comment: `str("ReportDate")` is not `str(hfIndexes$ReportDt)`

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich - Thanks again for your patience. I agree the two variables are not the same, but when I evaluate the structure of "ReportDate," it appears to be of POSIXct class

> str(lsHoldings$ReportDate)
 POSIXct[1:2247], format: "2010-10-31" "2011-01-31" "2011-04-30"
> str(lsHoldings$ReportDt)
 int [1:2247] 20101031 20110131 20110430 
> lsHoldingsZoo <- zoo(lsHoldings,order.by = "ReportDate")
> lsHoldingsXTS <-as.xts(lsHoldingsZoo, order.by = "ReportDate")
Error in xts(coredata(x), order.by = order.by, frequency = frequency,  : 
  order.by requires an appropriate time-based object

Comment: What I am having trouble with is formulating why "zoo" sees "ReportDate" as a time-based object, but "xts" does not. 

Sorry to be so naive and bothersome. I appreciate your attention and suggestions for improvement.

Comment: As I said before, look at the `hfIndexesZoo` object you created. zoo most certainly *does not* see `"ReportDate"` as a time-based object.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich - Well, you are correct. The Zoo object does not see "ReportDate" as a time-based object. 
‘zoo’ series from ReportDate to ReportDate
  Data: chr [1, 1:11] "AANNX" "50103" "20101031" "EMN" "0.016000" "0.0425" " 4" " 68.14437" "3.185563e+01" ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:11] "Symbol" "CrspNo" "ReportDt" "LipperCode" ...
  Index:  chr "ReportDate"

Now I'm at a loss. I thought I converted "ReportDt" to a time-based object, but I suppose not. How is it that the "ymd" function creates the POSIXct class, but zoo does not recognize it as such?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4297342/3253015

`order.by` is an argument needed in xts objects. As we are dealing with timeseries, you can consider it to be one, that creates a frame of sorts, into which the data is put. So you tell `as.xts` that the data you want inside is spaced out by the time-based object given in `order.by`.